# QtScript: how to reload current script?

Tags: qt, qtscript

QScriptEngine has evaluate() method that can be used to load script, execute it and to run a specified function from already loaded script. But how to clear current script and load a new one? For example, i use evaluate() to load a script from file and then evaluate() to get a script functions and call them. But what can i do to clear current script and load a new one from a different file? Deleting and creating QScriptEngine seems like a solution, but it likes to be created in GUI thread (due to QScriptEngineDebugger) while all script operations are performed in separate thread. So is it any way to clear current script without re-creating QScriptEngine object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem, and would like to improve Eye of Hell's answer (thanks, by the way!), as it leaves out an important detail.

I'll use a cut down version of my problem, where I am reusing a `QScriptEngine` object and wanted to ensure that nothing was left behind between evaluations. In particular, I wanted to ensure that the `onEquipped` function was not called for the `"RC Helicopter Controller"` entity, as it doesn't change its sprite when it is equipped and hence doesn't define an `onEquipped` function in its script file. Simply using `pushContext()` and `popContext()` results in nothing being called at all:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtScript>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QScriptEngine scriptEngine;

    scriptEngine.pushContext();
    scriptEngine.evaluate("function onEquipped(entity) { print('changing pixmap to equipped sprite for ' + entity); }").toString();
    QScriptValueList args;
    args << QScriptValue("Pistol");
    scriptEngine.globalObject().property("onEquipped").call(QScriptValue(), args);
    scriptEngine.popContext();

    scriptEngine.pushContext();
    args.clear();
    args << QScriptValue("RC Helicopter Controller");
    scriptEngine.globalObject().property("onEquipped").call(QScriptValue(), args);
    scriptEngine.popContext();

    return 0;
}
```

The function call seems to happen on the original context, not the current one. Upon looking at [QScriptEngine::pushContext()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscriptengine.html#pushContext) documentation, I saw that you need to explicitly use the context returned from it, and on top of that, you must use [QScriptEngine::activationContext()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscriptcontext.html#activationObject) to access any variables:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtScript>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QScriptEngine scriptEngine;

    scriptEngine.pushContext();
    scriptEngine.evaluate("function onEquipped(entity) { print('changing pixmap to equipped sprite for ' + entity); }").toString();
    QScriptValueList args;
    args << QScriptValue("Pistol");
    scriptEngine.currentContext()->activationObject().property("onEquipped").call(QScriptValue(), args);
    scriptEngine.popContext();

    scriptEngine.pushContext();
    args.clear();
    args << QScriptValue("RC Helicopter Controller");
    scriptEngine.currentContext()->activationObject().property("onEquipped").call(QScriptValue(), args);
    scriptEngine.popContext();

    return 0;
}
```

> changing pixmap to equipped sprite for Pistol

Answer (score 7):

```
engine.pushContext();
engine.evaluate("...");
engine.popContext();
engine.pushContext();
engine.evaluate("...");
engine.popContext();
```

Calling pushContext() before evaluating a script and calling popContext() before evaluating a new script will effectively clear all script data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set an empty object to http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qscriptengine.html#setGlobalObject

Maybe that works.

Comment: Global object just defines what 'this' will reference inside script :(. It has no connection to script code itself

Comment: Did you at least try it? As far as I remember, functions are part of this object.

Comment: QT functions available from script, not script functions.